# $array[]='something' analog in Laravel array session logic

Tags: php, laravel-5

I can create session array in Laravel only with defining `key` by hand using `Session::put('items.key','1')`, but I have a situation when I just need keys to be made automatically as I would use simple PHP function `$items[]=value`. How can I do this in Laravel session?

P.S. I have tried `Session::put('items[]','1')`, but it doesn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, I have find out, it works with `Session::push('items', $value)`